# FirebaseUser's profile is not updated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase Auth on Android.

My signin flow works fine but I can't update **username** & **profileUrl** right after.

```
public void test() {
    String username = "test username";
    Uri avatarUri = Uri.parse("http://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Wonderful-Random-Background.jpg");
    UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder builder = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder();
    builder.setDisplayName(username);
    builder.setPhotoUri(avatarUri);

    Log.d("UPDATE PROFILE", "user exists=" + (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null ? "YES" : "NO"));
    Log.d("UPDATE PROFILE", "user anonymous=" + (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().isAnonymous() ? "YES" : "NO"));
    firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().updateProfile(builder.build()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName() != null) {
                    Log.d("UPDATE PROFILE", "username=" + firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());
                } else {
                    Log.d("UPDATE PROFILE", "username=NULL");
                }
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl() != null) {
                    Log.d("UPDATE PROFILE", "photoUrl=" + firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl().toString());
                } else {
                    Log.d("UPDATE PROFILE", "photoUrl=NULL");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("UPDATE PROFILE", task.getException().getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

}
```

I tried the test method above and this is my output

> UPDATE PROFILE: user exists=YES
>
> UPDATE PROFILE: user anonymous=NO
>
> UPDATE PROFILE: username=NULL
>
> UPDATE PROFILE: photoUrl=NULL

I don't understand why my currentUser is not updated even with a "isSuccessful()" result

Comment: Mine was working fine earlier, but then I started getting that problem.. If you log out and in again, it usually fills it in though... It doesn't seem to update right away for some reason.

Comment: @AubtinSamai Yes , It didn't update right away

Comment: I hope they gonna fix it asap

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue in the latest release of Firebase (9.8.0). It's a known issue according to [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/409). The only temp fix right now is to rollback everything to version 9.6.1.

Change your gradle dependencies for the app to this for Firebase components (this is just a temp fix, and it could break something else if using something in new version):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
```

Change those matching ones in your grandle to the versions specified above.

Comment: Yes unfortunately even with version 10.0.0 the bug remains ... :(

Comment: Also seeing this in 10.0.1