# Firebase user authentication update display name not updated in instance user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello i am using firebase authenication - android- for my app , everthing is working good, but when i update the name for one user using this code

```
UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                    .setDisplayName(newname)
                    .build();

            user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                updateUser();
                                name.setText(user.getDisplayName());
                                Toast.makeText(context,"Your name has successfully updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                ((MainActivity)context).updatedrawerProfile();

                            }
                        }
                    });
```

the name is updated, but i have to signout and login again to see the updated name so if i try to display the new name after update using this code :

```
user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
System.out.print(user.getDisplayName());
```

the previous name printed not the new one ,so my question how to refresh the user information without logout ?

Comment: This is a known issue in Firebase Authentication 9.8 and 10.0. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723639/firebaseusers-profile-is-not-updated