# Updating FirebaseUser DisplayName (email auth) isn't updating instance CurrentUser

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

This might be similar to this: [FirebaseUser's profile is not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723639/firebaseusers-profile-is-not-updated)

However, I'm not confident in my Flutter skills to be sure. I'm trying to update DisplayName in Firebase and then have the `currentUser.displayName`. The updateProfile seems to run just fine, but the currentUser doesn't update with the new displayName even after a reload() call.

I'm hoping anyone could tell me if I'm doing something wrong, or chalk it up to a bug in Firebase.

My code:

```
Future _update(FirebaseUser user, String displayName) async {
  UserUpdateInfo _updateData= new UserUpdateInfo();
  _updateData.displayName = displayName;
  await user.updateProfile(_updateData);
  await user.reload();
  setState(() {
    _currentDisplayName = user.displayName;
  });
}
```

Comment: For reference, this seems to be related: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20390

Comment: I've used the above to create a workaround that utilizes `Future.Delayed` for 3 seconds after the `currentUser().reload()` and then reinitializing the `FirebaseAuth.instance`.

Comment: can you give me a hand here, as how you resolved it? I am implementing something similar wherein, user updates their name when tapping `save` button. Currently on my `onTap` method, I've this code : https://pastebin.com/gem16ZWU. Can you let me know if I am missing anything there ? And what's the next step to make it work ? ie save name successfully and retrieve it as well ? Appreciate your help here. @themene

Answer (score 4):

it work for me

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((val) {
      UserUpdateInfo updateUser = UserUpdateInfo();
      updateUser.displayName = myFullName;
      updateUser.photoUrl = picURL;
      val.updateProfile(updateUser);
    });
```

Comment: Your code updates the info just fine, but it isn't immediately available to the app even after `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().reload()` which is the heart of my issue.